# C++ log precision error for double vector array?

Tags: c++, vector, floating-point-precision, double-precision

I have double vector array ( vector< double > ) and its max value ( 1 ) and min value ( 0 ).

When I did below sub operation, log gives (1.#INF00000000000000000) for max value's index that ( 1 - 1.000000000000001 ) ( double precison ).

How can I prevent this precision error?

```
log( 1 - array[ i ] );
```

Comment: You need to get a more precise data type. For example: http://gmplib.org/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
if(array[i] >= 1)
  return 0;
else if(array[i] <= 0)
  return std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
else
  return log(1 - array[i]);
```